# Julia - Remove vertices and edges with Graphs.jl

Tags: graph, julia

I built a medium-size graph and I need to clean it, i.e. to remove some vertices and edges.

Is there a nice way to proceed using the Graphs.jl library?
Or can this only be done with LightGraphs.jl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems not to be possible in Graphs.jl; there is an [issue](https://github.com/JuliaArchive/Graphs.jl/issues/73) from 2014, which mentions the problem, but has since not been updated, and probably never will be, since the package no longer seems to be maintained actively (cf. its readme). You might be able to find some working code in one of the pull requests, though, eg. [here](https://github.com/JuliaArchive/Graphs.jl/pull/87).

But LightGraphs.jl certainly [has these functions](https://juliagraphs.github.io/LightGraphs.jl/latest/generators.html#LightGraphs.rem_edge!), and I have the impression that it is under active development and has a growing infrastructure around it, too.

Comment: I have used LightGraphs.jl in several production applications and I can recommend it as well maintained. The only thing you should be careful about is that removing vertices from a graph reorders them.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, yes this is what I was hoping it wouldn't be... I had no other choices than changing all my code from a Graphs.jl to a MetaGraph.jl library based.. Took some time but now I can remove edges and vertices.

Comment: @alexo, be aware that we currently have a bug in MetaGraphs related to removal of vertices: https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/MetaGraphs.jl/issues/22. We're pretty busy at the moment getting JuliaGraphs ready for 0.7, but I hope to revisit this soon.